# Partial limits of sequence of trigonometric functions

Tags: calculus, limits

I  need to find all partial limits of$a_n=1+\frac{n+1}{n+3}\cos\frac{n\pi}{2} $, how I suppose to know what subsequences exactly to choose?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What does partial limit mean ? Does it mean all cluster points ?

Comment: @Amr I mean limits of subsequences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\cos(\frac{n\pi}{2})=0$ for odd n, $cos(\frac{n\pi}{2})=-1$ for $n=2 (mod4) $, $cos(\frac{n\pi}{2})=1$ for $n=0 (mod 4)$

Comment: Why do you choose mode 4, not 5,6 or any else number why 4?Thanks.

Comment: OK. I will put this in my answer.

Comment: @  Amr Thanks, waiting for your explain